# How to achieve the short particle bursts in this gif?

Tags: after-effects, premiere, editing, effects, special-effects

I've tried to create the short bursts similar to this gif but I can't seem to get the exact effect. I'm using particle world in after effects. Another problem I'm running into is the texture has some color overlay I can't get rid of.

[image: gif]

Comment: Could you post what you've produced already? That might help us hone in on what you could be doing differently. That should also let us see the color overlay problem you've mentioned.

Comment: I got it, thanks. I had to use Particular. Particle World couldn't achieve what I was trying to do. The clip I'm working on is NSFW. I didn't think it would be appropriate to post.

Comment: You could post that as an answer, along with what you needed to configure - you are allowed to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Generally its totally possible to achieve this with Particle World, just play around with gravity adn particle emission rate and animate them accordingly.

If you need a more advanced particle system use a plugin called [Particular](http://www.redgiant.com/products/all/trapcode-particular/) by Red Giant Software. Though its not free and costs money.